# How to handle error when ID is not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the best way to handle the error then ID is not found?
I have this code in my controller:

```
  def show
    @match = Match.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I was thinking about something like this:

```
  def show
    if @match = Match.find(params[:id])
    else
      render 'error'
    end
  end
```

But I still get:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MatchesController#show
>
> Couldn't findMatch with 'id'=2

Why?

What is the correct solution?

Comment: `@match = Match.find_by_id(params[:id])` if record doesn't exist @match would hold `nil`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Rescue it in the base controller and leave your action code as simple as possible.
You don't want to deal not found exception in every action, do you?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_404

  def render_404
    render :template => "errors/error_404", :status => 404
  end
end
```

Comment: +1. and please make a custom 404 page with sweet cute cats, doing some random stuff, while saying 404. everybody loves that!

Answer (score 7):

By default the `find` method raises an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception. The correct way of handling a not found record is:

```
def show
  @match = Match.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  render 'error'
end
```

However, if you prefer an if/else approach, you can use the `find_by_id` method that will return nil:

```
def show
  @match = Match.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if @match.nil?     # or unless @match
    render 'error'
  end
end
```

Comment: unless @match=Match.find_by(id: params[:id])
render 'error'
end #is doing the same and saves line of code :P

Comment: of course, but I highly prefer readable code to short code :D

Comment: render :error unless @match # that should be the best for your fit :P

Comment: oh yes, that is what I'd use normally (or the @xdazz solution). I just used a more friendly syntax because it looks like the OP is still missing some points in the Ruby language, let alone the Rails framework...

Answer (score 1):

You can use find_by_id method it returns nil instead of throwing exception

```
    Model.find_by_id
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two approaches missing:

One is to use a Null-Object (there I leave research up to you)

Te other one was mentioned, but can be placed more reusable and in a way more elegantly (but it is a bit hidden from you action code because it 
works on a somewhat higher level and hides stuff):

```
class MyScope::MatchController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_match, only: [:show]

  def show
    # will only render if params[:id] is there and resolves
    # to a match that will then be available in @match.
  end

  private

  def set_match
    @match = Match.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if !@match.present?
      # Handle somehow, i.e. with a redirect
      redirect_to :back, alert: t('.match_not_found')
    end
  end
end
```